# .bat script output comparison

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to adjust power/seep settings on windows 10 using a .bat file.  I found that you can easily import a power scheme using the `powercfg -import` however the issues is trying to set the power scheme as the active one.  In order to use `powercfg -setactive GUID` However, I need to know the GUID to set it as active.  The GUID changes computer to computer though.

Here is what I am using to pull the output of `powercfg /L` to put it into variables:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powercfg.exe /L`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
ECHO %var3%
ENDLOCAL
```

I have no way of putting just the GUID into a variable to put into the set active command.  I am unsure of how to pull out just a specific word or phrase.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I extract all the GUIDs from the output of `powercfg /l`?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('powercfg.exe /L ^| findstr GUID') do (
  set /a _count+=1
  set _output=%%f
  for /f "tokens=4" %%g in ('echo !_output!') do (
    set _guid[!_count!]=%%g
    )
  )
for /l %%f in (1, 1, %_count%) do (
  echo GUID %%f = !_guid[%%f]!
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- use `findstr` to find the lines containing GUID
- if you want to find a particular scheme by name then replace `findstr GUID` with `findstr %1` and then run `test schemename`
- the GUID is the 4th token, extract that from the output with another `for /f`
- `usebackq` is not needed if you use `'`
- use `for /l` to loop through the saved GUIDs

Example:

```
F:\test>powercfg /l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

F:\test>test
GUID 1 = 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
GUID 2 = 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
GUID 3 = a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a

F:\test>
```

---

#### How can I extract the active GUID from the output of `powercfg /l`?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('powercfg.exe /L ^| findstr ^*') do (
  set _output=%%f
  for /f "tokens=4" %%g in ('echo !_output!') do (
    set _guid=%%g
    )
  )
echo %_guid%
endlocal
```

Notes:

- the active power scheme is terminated with `*`, use `findstr` to find that line in the output
- the GUID is the 4th token, extract that from the output with another `for /f`
- `usebackq` is not needed if you use `'`

Output:

```
F:\test>powercfg /l

Existing Power Schemes (* Active)
-----------------------------------
Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Balanced) *
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Power saver)

F:\test>test
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For /f- Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [For /l - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: Isn't the authors problem that he is importing a new power scheme (which will get a random GUID) and he wants to set that new power scheme to be the active one? So wouldn't he need to look for the name of his scheme with findstr and extract the GUID from that result (instead of getting the GUID from the currently active one which is most likely one of the Windows default ones)? Also one can use "powercfg  /getactivescheme" to only get the current active scheme (same format as /l but only 1 row) which eliminates the need for findstr when searching for the active power scheme GUID.

Comment: @User025 Good point. However the question is not very clear ... :/

Comment: It doesn't say what is the one s/he wants.

Comment: @Mark Addressed in revised answer

Comment: @User025 Addressed in revised answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Import Power Config
powercfg -import C:\Windows\Temp\Never-Sleep.pow

::Get GUID of Never-Sleep
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('powercfg.exe /L ^| findstr ^Never-Sleep') do (
  set _output=%%f
  for /f "tokens=4" %%g in ('echo !_output!') do (
    set _guid=%%g
    )
  )

::Set Power Config to Active
powercfg %_guid%

endlocal
```